# AngularJS two-way binding. Returning user inserted input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input, return

User inserts value in the HTML:

```
</div>`<div ng-app="xpCalc" ng-controller="Xp Calculator">

<p>Insert your current Level  <input type="number" ng-model="currentLevel"></p>

<h2>{{$scope.currentXp}}</h2>

</div>`
```

And my js script calculates and returns the results:

```
var app=angular.module('xpCalc', []);
app.controller('Xp Calculator', function($scope){
$scope.currentLevel;
$scope.currentXp=function(){
    var output=0;
    for (var thisLVL =1; thisLVL >= $scope.currentLevel; thisLVL++) {
        return output += ( Math.floor ( thisLVL + 300 * Math.pow( 2, thisLVL / 7 ) ) / 4 );
    }}});
```

But somehow I don't see the results in the view. What can be wrong?

Comment: first you dont need to use `$scope` in `{}` and secondly `currentXp` is a method, so you have to use `currentXp()`

Comment: There are a few things wrong, but in order to help you, I need to understand what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to perform some sort of calculation on the user's input?

Comment: Could it be because you're `return` is breaking your loop before the output is actually computed?

Comment: Randi Radcliff, Yes I'm doing a some sort of calculation on the user input.

Comment: @OsmanCea: No, you cannot break a `for` loop that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<div ng-app="xpCalc" ng-controller="xpCalculatorController">

<p>Insert your current Level  <input type="number" ng-model="currentLevel"></p>

<h2>{{currentXp()}}</h2>

</div>
```

and

```
var app=angular.module('xpCalc', []);
app.controller('xpCalculatorController', function($scope){
$scope.currentLevel = 1;
$scope.currentXp=function(){
    var output=0;
    for (var thisLVL =1; thisLVL <= $scope.currentLevel; thisLVL++) {
        output += ( Math.floor ( thisLVL + 300 * Math.pow( 2, thisLVL / 7 ) ) / 4 );
    }
    return output;
  }
});
```

Note: your loop operator `>=` was inverted and infinite, changed to `<=`. Also, you cannot name your controller `Xp Calculator` with a space...

See https://plnkr.co/edit/BMomweYVGLlTsv2tTjfS?p=preview

Comment: The loop goes till it reaches the inserted value, let's say 50 and then it stops. The value is a sum of all the levels from 1 to 50. I tried your method but it still display {{currentXp()}}

Comment: I changed `>=` to `<=`

Comment: Yeah it works on pllunkr, but somehow I can't get that display on my index.html page, the text editor I use is sublime 3. But knowing that the code is good I really thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
angular.module('xpCalc')
  .controller('FooCtrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.calculate = function(currentLevel) {
           $scope.currentXp = 0;
           for (var thisLVL = 1; thisLVL <= currentLevel; thisLVL++) {
               $scope.currentXp += (Math.floor(thisLVL + 300 * Math.pow(2, thisLVL / 7)) / 4);
           }
       };
  });
```

and in the view put a button that triggers it

```
  <div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
     <p>Insert your current Level
         <input type="number" ng-model="currentLevel">
     </p>
     <button type="button" ng-click="calculate(currentLevel)">Calcular</button>
     <div ng-show="currentXp !== undefined">
         <h2>{{currentXp}}</h2>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

HTML:

```
<p>Insert your current Level  <input type="number" ng-model="currentLevel"></p>
<h2>{{currentXp()}}</h2>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$scope.currentLevel;
$scope.currentXp=function(){
   if ($scope.currentLevel) {
     var output=0;        
     for (i =1; i < $scope.currentLevel; i++) {
         output += ( Math.floor ( i + 300 * Math.pow( 2, i / 7 ) ) / 4 );
     }
     return output
   }
}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/e4af6bLs/2/